# Google Cloud attached disk size incorrect

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to create a compute instance on Google Cloud with a 20TB disk attached, but I'm seeing something strange.  When I specify the size of the disk size in the gcloud command I do not see that same disk size reflected when I check the size of the instance.  I've also tried creating new disks and attaching them, resizing the attached disks, but it does not go about 2TB.  Is 2TB the max disk size for compute instances?

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance --boot-disk-size 10TB --scopes storage-rw
Created [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project/zones/us-central1-a/instances/instance].
NAME    ZONE           MACHINE_TYPE   PREEMPTIBLE  INTERNAL_IP  EXTERNAL_IP     STATUS
instance  us-central1-a  n1-standard-1               10.240.0.2   104.154.45.175  RUNNING
$ gcloud compute ssh gm-vcf
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.8994721896014059218' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.

user@instance:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       2.0T  880M  1.9T   1% /
udev             10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs           743M  8.3M  735M   2% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can attach up to 64TB of Standard Persistent Disk per VM for most machine types, you can refer to [this blogpost](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2016/02/Compute-Engine-now-with-3-TB-of-high-speed-Local-SSD-and-64-TB-of-Persistent-Disk-per-VM.html) for details. You need to resize the file system so that the operating system can access the additional space on your disk. You can refer to [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#formatting) for steps to resize the disk.

Comment: Thanks. That was perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's not the disk size, but the partition size (you can confirm by running `fdisk -l` and checking the disk size). Depending on how the disk is partitioned, the maximum size will be 2 TB. Perhaps it'd be better to use a smaller disk for the system and attach another one that is bigger to store the data (this new one you'd be able to partition as you'd like)